# How can I programing multiple cores in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I have a program and want to increase the runtime performance more.

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

let c = a + b;
let d = c + 2;

let e = 3;

let f = c + d;
let g = a + e;
```

Step 1: Because a, b and e are independent so I want to execute them in parallel (different cores).

Step 2: Because c is depended on a and b; g is depended on a and e, but c and g are independent each other so execute c and g after step 1 but in parallel.

Step 3: Because d is depended on c so they are executed after step 2.

Step 4: Because f is depended on c and d, so it is executed after step 3.

Can we achieve this one with C or any programing language support this natively?

Comment: Simple programs like this will never be more efficient on multicore systems. Multiple cores become relevant once the advantage of running tasks in parallel outweigh the overhead (of having to synchronise threads) and complexity.

Comment: Yep, it is a sample only, but for a complex program, I think we have the same logic, independent lines code will be executed in the same time, the dependence lines will be executed after the dependent.

Comment: @MarkSmith: Multi-core parallelization doesn't happen on a line-of-code to line-of-code level. It's usually done by running entire *functions* (multiple times) in parallel using threads. However for this to make any sense whatsoever, the problem must be complex enough so that the overhead of managing the parallelization doesn't cost more than any concurrency speedups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-threading is clearly not suited for your problem. The synchronization/data-movement time is far bigger than the time to compute an addition of two native-typed values (eg. floating-point number, integers, etc.). Indeed, adding two integers take about 1 cycle on mainstream x86-64 processors while the time to move data from one cache of a core to another one takes at least several dozens of cycles (if not hundreds regarding the target architecture). Thus, using multiple cores will actually slow down massively the code. Multi-threading only worth it for a relatively heavy grained computation (at least few microseconds and generally even a bit more).

Fortunately, modern processors can execute multiple instructions in parallel per cycle (see [Instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) and [Superscalar processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor)). For example, an Intel Skylake can execute 4 addition per cycle. It can also execute instructions in an out-of-order way. A processor can detect dependencies for you so you do not need to do much. You just need to ensure instructions are independent so they can be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is "multi-threading". Most modern progressing languages have built-in support for this concept (for example C++'s `std::thread`, C is a bit ancient but multi-threading support was added in the 2011 standard update (known as C11) using the [threads.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) header. The new API is optional and while many common C implementations do offer support, the one you use may not.

Luckily, threading has been used extensively with C, before the 2011 standard update, and there are multiple non-standard APIs for threading that you can use as libraries. For example, check out [pthread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) as a common cross platform threading library for C.

Comment: No, it isn't multiple threading. Multiple threading is "tasks" execution in the same time. Here for independent line code execution.

Comment: C has older *heritage* than C++ (which is still pretty old itself), but the latest version dates from 2017.  Since the 2011 version of the C language specification, it has had built-in multi-threading support, albeit as an optional feature.

Comment: @MarkSmith "independent line code execution" is instruction-level parallelism, it is not related to CPU cores. Modern CPU cores have pipelines which already execute instructions in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSmith - it is indeed multi-threading, which is the general concept of a single program running on more than one processor (core) where multiple execution paths have parallel access to the same memory - in your case, both computing `c` and `g` requires access to `a`. The distinction you draw is without a difference.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - granted. It is even implemented in quite a bit modern C implementation. I should have pointed that out, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think we have a bit different here, nobody will create multiple threads for variable assignment :) Check @jérôme-richard answer